# how to update a values in hashmap

Tags: hashmap

i have stored a Serialno, name, price, quantity in a dynamic listview using hashmap.

something like this.

sno    name    price    quantity
1      xyz     1         2
2      xys     2         2
3      xxx     3         3

I am deleting the element on a button click. But when i delete the element of first row the serial number of the first row remains same(2). I want to auto update the serial number such that the serial number(2) becomes 1 and serial number 3 becomes 2.

Pls anybody tell me how to do it.

Comment: consider specifying the language you are using.

Comment: Please edit the question and  write your program to understand the question clearly.